# Promises not waiting for each other in my nodejs controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I got 4 promises here, and I thought that it would run the first one, then wait until its finished, THEN run the next one, wait till finished and THEN run the next one etc..

But what happens here is that it runs all of them all at once and does not wait for anything to finish.

This is my promise chain:

```
// 
// Run the promises
// 
findBanks
    .then(findReceipts)
    .then(findExpenses)
    .then(sendResult)
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("getbankAccountReport ERR: " + err);
        res.json({error:true,err})
    });
```

This is the output from my console.log

```
=====findAllBank=====
=====findAllReceipt=====
=====findAllExpense=====
=====RESOLVE findAllBank=====
=====sendResult=====
=====RESOLVE sendResult=====
=====RESOLVE findAllReceipt=====
=====RESOLVE findAllExpense=====
```

Am I not understanding promises correct or?

Anyway here is my nodejs controller:

```
    exports.getBankAccountReport = function(req, res) {

        // 
        // Find all bank accounts
        // 
        var bankModel = require('../models/bankModel');
        var bankTable = mongoose.model('bankModel');
        var bankArray = [];
        var findAllBank = new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("=====findAllBank=====")
            bankTable.aggregate([
                ...lots of mongo stuff...
                ],function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    bankArray = data;
                    console.log("=====RESOLVE findAllBank=====")
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('findBank ERROR : ' + err));
                }
            });
        });


        // 
        // Find the RECEIPT for each bank account
        // 
        var receiptModel = require('../models/receiptModel');
        var receiptTable = mongoose.model('receiptModel');
        var receiptArray = [];
        var findAllReceipt = new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("=====findAllReceipt=====")
            receiptTable.aggregate([
                ...lots of mongo stuff...
                ], function (err, data) {
                    if (!err) {
                        receiptArray = data;
                        console.log("=====RESOLVE findAllReceipt=====")
                        resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('findReceipts ERROR : ' + err));
                    }
            });
        });


        // 
        // Find the EXPENSE for each bank account
        // 
        var expenseModel = require('../models/expenseModel');
        var expenseTable = mongoose.model('expenseModel');
        var expenseArray = [];
        var findAllExpense = new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("=====findAllExpense=====")
            expenseTable.aggregate([
                ...lots of mongo stuff...
                ], function (err, data) {
                    if (!err) {
                        expenseArray = data;
                        console.log("=====RESOLVE findAllExpense=====")
                        resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('findExpense ERROR : ' + err));
                    }
            });
        });

        var sendResult = function(data) {
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                console.log("=====sendResult=====")
                res.json({error:false,  
                          "bank":bankArray, 
                          "receipt":receiptArray, 
                          "expense":expenseArray})
                console.log("=====RESOLVE sendResult=====")
                resolve();
            });
            return promise;
        };

    // 
    // Run the promises
    // 
    findAllBank
        .then(findAllReceipt)
        .then(findAllExpense)
        .then(sendResult)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            console.log("getbankAccountReport ERR: " + err);
            res.json({error:true,err})
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried to learn from this example, so I really dont understand why my controller is not working:   https://html5hive.org/how-to-chain-javascript-promises/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your Promises in functions

```
var findAllBank = function() {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("=====findAllBank=====")
        bankTable.aggregate([
            ...lots of mongo stuff...
            ],function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                bankArray = data;
                console.log("=====RESOLVE findAllBank=====")
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('findBank ERROR : ' + err));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When resolved, the next function in the chain will be called with the data passed in the resolve() function.

**Do no confuse the Promise and the function that builds it**

When you create a `new Promise(executor)`, you instanciate a new object that will have two methods (functions of an object), `.then(resolveCB [, rejectCB])` and `.catch(rejectCB)`.

The aime is to know, whenever a process is done, if it was successful or if it failed, and the continue accordingly.

```
var myFirstPromise = new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { resolve('resolved'); });
```

In other words, those methods are used to continue your process once the promise defined by `executor` is settled. It can either get `fulfilled` and call the `resolveCB` callback (using`then`), or `rejected` and call the `rejectCB`callback (using both `then` and `catch`). A callback (resolveCB or rejectCB) is a function, not a Promise itself, even if the callback might return a Promise.

```
myFirstPromise
    .then(function resolveCB(result) { console.log(result); }) //you can use a 2nd callback for rejection at this point
    .catch(function rejectCB(err) { console.log(err); });

myFirstPromise
    .then(
        function resolveCB(result) { console.log(result); } // if resolved
      , function rejectCB(err) { console.log(err); } // if rejected
    )
    .catch(function rejectCB(err) { console.log(err); }); // NEVER forget the last catch, just my 2cents :)
```

We saw the inputs of `.then()` and `.catch()` but what about their return value? The both of them will return a new Promise. That's why you can chain the `.then()`'s and `.catch()`'s.

```
myFirstPromise
    .then(function resolveCB1(result) { console.log(result); })
    .then(function resolveCB2(result) { console.log(result); }) // console.log is called but result is undefined
    .catch(function rejectCB1(err) { console.log(err); });
myFirstPromise
    .then(function resolveCB3(result) { 
        throw 'I threw an exception';  // an exception is thrown somewhere in the code
        console.log(result); 
    })
    .then(function resolveCB4(result) { console.log(result); })
    .catch(function rejectCB2(err) { console.log(err); }); // a promise in the chain get rejected or error occured
```

In the previous example, we see that our second `.then()` is hit but `result` is undefined. The promise returned by first `.then()` fullfiled but no value as been passed by the executor to the resolve callback `resolveCB2`. In the second case, an exception occured in `resolveCB3`, it gets rejected so `rejectCB2` is called. If we want our resolve callbacks to receive an argument, we have to notify the exector. To do so, the simplest way is for the callbacks to return a value:

```
myFirstPromise
    .then(function resolveCB1(result) {
        console.log(result);
        result += ' again';
        return result;
    })
    .then(function resolveCB2(result) { 
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    })
    .catch(function rejectCB1(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Now that's said, you've got all the pieces together for understanding a `Promise`. Let's try to sum it up in a cleaner way:

```
var myFirstPromise = new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { resolve('resolved'); })
  , resolveCB = function resolveCB(result) {
        console.log(result);
        result += ' again';
        return result;
    }
  , resolveLastCB = function resolveLastCB(result) {
        console.log(result);
        result += ' and again';
        return result;
    }
  , justLog = function justLog(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
  ;
myFirstPromise
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveLastCB)
    .then(justLog)
    .catch(justLog);
```

You can now chan them nicely, it's cool and all

```
myFirstPromise
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveCB)
    .then(resolveLastCB)
    .then(justLog)
    .catch(justLog);
```

But what if your Promise chain 'really' changes and you need to get rid of `myFirstPromise` and start with `resolveCB` instead ? It's just a function, it can be executed but doesn't have any `.then()` or `.catch()` method. It's not a Promise. You can't do `resolveCB.then(resolveLastCB)`, it will thow an error resolveCB.then( is not a function or something similar. You might think this is a gross mistake, I didn't call `resolveCB` and `resolveCB().then(resolveLastCB)` should work? Unfortunalty for those who thought about that, it's still wrong. `resolveCB` returns a string, some characters, not a `Promise`.

In order to avoid this kind of maintenance issue, you should know that the resolve and reject callbacks can return a `Promise` instead of a value. To do so, we'll use what's called the factory pattern. In simple words, the factory pattern is about instanciating new object using a (static) function instead of using the constructor directly.

```
var myFirstPromiseFactory = function myFirstPromiseFactory() { 
        /*
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
            resolve('resolved'); 
        });

        if you just need to resolve a Promise, this is a quicker way
        */
        return Promise.resolve('resolved');
    }
  , resolveFactory = function resolveFactory(result) {
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {             
            result = result || 'I started the chain';
            console.log(result);
            result += ' again';
            return resolve(result); // you can avoid the return keyword if you want, I use it as a matter of readability
        })
    }
  , resolveLastFactory = function resolveLastFactory(result) {
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { 
            console.log(result);
            result += ' and again';
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }
  , justLogFactory = function justLogFactory(result) {          
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { 
            console.log(result);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }
  ;
myFirstPromiseFactory() //!\\ notice I call the function so it returns a new Promise, previously we started directly with a Promise
    .then(resolveFactory)
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);
// Now you can switch easily, just call the first one
resolveFactory()
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);

justLogFactory('I understand Javascript')
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);
```

Factory functions might come handy when iterating over an array. It might be used to produce an array of promise given an input:

```
var myFirstPromiseFactory = function myFirstPromiseFactory() { 
        /*
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
            resolve('resolved'); 
        });

        if you just need to resolve a Promise, this is a quicker way
        */
        return Promise.resolve('resolved');
    }
  , resolveFactory = function resolveFactory(result) {
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {             
            result = result || 'I started the chain';
            console.log(result);
            result += ' again';
            return resolve(result); // you can avoid the return keyword if you want, I use it as a matter of readability
        })
    }
  , resolveLastFactory = function resolveLastFactory(result) {
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { 
            console.log(result);
            result += ' and again';
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }
  , justLogFactory = function justLogFactory(result) {          
        return new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) { 
            console.log(result);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }
  , concatValues = function concatValues(values) {
        return Promise.resolve(values.join(' '));
    }
  , someInputs =  [
        'I am an input'
      , 'I am a second input'
      , 'I am a third input'
      , 'I am yet an other input'
    ]
  ;
myFirstPromiseFactory() //!\\ notice I call the function so it returns a new Promise, previously we started directly with a Promise
    .then(resolveFactory)
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);
// Now you can switch easily, just call the first one
resolveFactory()
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);

justLogFactory('I understand Javascript')
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);

// Using a factory functions to create an array of promise usable with Promise.all()
var promiseArray = someInputs.map(function(input) {
    return justLogFactory(input);
});
Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(concatValues)
    .then(resolveLastFactory)
    .then(justLogFactory)
    .catch(justLogFactory);
```

Comment: Ahh like I did with the sendResult function?  - ok let me try and get back to you :)

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: I tried it with your function but get an `"TypeError: findAllBank.then is not a function"` error

Comment: `findAllBank().then`, you must call the function for it to return ('start') the promise.

Comment: Ok that made the findAllBank work - let me do the rest as well and see :)

Comment: YES!!! - Now it works exactly like it should! - So you do not create new promises, you create functions and let them RETURN a new promise.  Got it! - Thanks a lot Booster :-)

Comment: Hmm... in another controller, this does not work because I use `Promise.all([findProperties, findBookings])
  .then(mergeResult) `
In this case I should not wrap findProperties and findBookings in functions correct?  Or should I make them just new promises or just make them plain functions?

Comment: @Booster2ooo could you explain to me why do we need to wrap the Promises in function and return it from there?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard `Promise.all()` takes an array of Promise as argument, not functions. `then` and `catch` uses callback functions. You need to distinguish a factory, a promise and a callback in term of design.

Comment: @SanchitKapoor a Promise is an instance of an object that will handle a process (usually an async function) that can either be successful (resolved) or fail (rejected). When you create `new Promise`, you create an object that just wait for completion or failure, and when it does, will fire a callback (`then(resolveCB, rejectCB)` or `catch(rejectCB)`). Those callbacks are functions. if you want to continue a Promise chain, you'd better make those functions return a new Promise.

Comment: @Booster2ooo Got it, thanks.  Just got confused that in one case you need to define a function that returns a promise, and in the other (promise.all) you have to define a list of promises.

Comment: @SanchitKapoor thanks for clarifying - so the reason a function returns a promise is so you can continue the chain. I think I understand this a lot better now :)

Comment: @Booster2ooo and thanks for the good long explanation.  I learned a lot from that.  When you say "factory pattern", it has nothing to do with the factory that you can build in the app.js right?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard It's not only about "continuing the chain" but about maintainability and "interoperability", switching one promise by an other. You could create a promises chain by declaring only one promise at the top and always returning a value in your callbacks, the then/catch will continue to return a promise each time. Still, I think it's a bit misleading, it's clearer if your callbacks return the promise themselfts, and then you can swap them as you like.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard I don't understand what you mean by 'it has nothing to do with the factory that you can build in the app.js right?', but I guess it has. The factory pattern, is just a "way to do things", a concept. It's about using functions or even reflection to instanciante objects instead of directly calling the constructor (new Something).

Comment: @Booster2ooo I got confused, was thinking of the factory / services in angular :-)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard you don't need to pay so much attention to the term factory, it's just a common concept. I hope you understood the differece between a Promise and the callbacks (functions) you have to pass to then/catch, that's the most important part. I'll edit the article to show an other example of factory being used with Promise.All() which will maybe make more sense.